# C# Populate Gridview from Dropdown choice

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, drop-down-menu

I have tried everything but can not figure out how to populate a gridview with my dropdown selection.  I have checked the value of the dropdown and it is correct and the gridview will display all items but not the items that I want.  I am using a web form.  Below is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Populate();
        }

        protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
            myConnection.Open();

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = null;
                string serverIP = drpChoose.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from ScheduledTasks WHERE ServerIP = " + serverIP, myConnection);

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            myConnection.Close();
        }

        public void Populate()
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
            myConnection1.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ServerIP FROM Servers", myConnection1);
            SqlDataReader dropReader;
            dropReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            drpChoose.DataSource = dropReader;
            drpChoose.DataTextField = "ServerIP";
            drpChoose.DataValueField = "ServerIP";
            drpChoose.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use stored procedures if you are using SQL Server, with actual parameters associated with the SQLCommand object.

Comment: I got it working my creating a parameter for serverIP and then setting that to my variable serverIP.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You should also apply sql parameterization.  It will help prevent SQL injection attacks.  Which your code is currently vulnerable to.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx](http://SQL%20Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need rebind the dropdownlist after each post back otherwise you will loose the selected item. Try the below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
            Populate();                
            }

    }

    protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            string serverIP = drpChoose.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from ScheduledTasks WHERE ServerIP = " + serverIP, myConnection);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        myConnection.Close();
    }

    public void Populate()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
        myConnection1.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ServerIP FROM Servers", myConnection1);
        SqlDataReader dropReader;
        dropReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        drpChoose.DataSource = dropReader;
        drpChoose.DataTextField = "ServerIP";
        drpChoose.DataValueField = "ServerIP";
        drpChoose.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: This still did not work.  My Grid is not displaying.  However, when I change my SQL Command to SELECT * FROM TABLE without the WHERE, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Page_Load method to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack()) {
        Populate();
    }
}
```

On every page load, you are rebinding the dropdown selection so that the default "all" value will always be set.  By using the Page.IsPostBack property, you're telling the page to only bind on the first load and not subsequent postbacks.  By using this property, the selected item in the dropdown list will not change on postbacks.

MSDN: [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

**Update**

Regarding your comment about the "Where" clause in your SQL statement, is serverIP stored in the database as text? Try wrapping serverIP in apostrophes like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from ScheduledTasks WHERE ServerIP = '" + serverIP + "'', myConnection);
```

Comment: I am getting serverIP from the dropdownlist which is being populated from SQL.  string serverIP = drpChoose.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(); I have tested the value of serverIP and it appears to be working.

Comment: Yes but how is the serverIP stored in SQL Server?  What is its data type?

Comment: I got it working by creating a parameter.  Yes it is stored as text.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guide: Why not use the Ajaxtoolkit UpdatePanel control. 
Put the Gridview in the UpdatePanel, then set the dropdown selection as the Updatetrigger for the Gridview.Then you won't have to worry about postback and values.